Can wider pickets in my PVC fence be replaced with narrower ones without replacing the top and bottom rail?
My contractor installed a very nice white vinyl pool safety fence along the dock in my yard. However he did not research the code for my town. According to code, 20 ft from the water the fence must be "open". Which means the space between the pickets must be twice the size of the pickets. So now they must be replaced. He wants to just replace the wider pickets with narrower ones. I am concerned because the holes in the top and bottom rails were made for the wider pickets. How can the narrower ones possibly, not only stay, but look nice?

As a contractor, He must perform work in accordance with code.  This is a problem he /she need to correct.  It also need to be corrected to your approval.
